# is there any analytic function f on open unit disk $f(0)=1/2$ , $f(1/2)=1/3$ and $f(1/3)=1/4$

Tags: complex-analysis

is the  following statement is true?
there exists an analytic function $f$ on open unit disk $f(0)=1/2$ , $f(1/2)=1/3$ and $f(1/3)=1/4$

---

can anyone help me please.I have no idea how to solve this problem

Answer (score 3):

We can fit a polynomial through any $n$ points, for instance, look at [Lagrange interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial). Clearly, the polynomials are analytic.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: start with $ 3(x-1/2)(x-1/3)$